# getopt command line get values c++

Tags: c++

How do you get the values of the flags in getopt, I have tried googling it but all I got is on how to switch cases and set flags. I got the below code and what I am trying to do is to have three flags, -a, -b, -c but only two flags are passed like `./filename -a somevalue -c anothervalue` or `./filename -b somevalue -c anothervalue` any help?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int flagA = 0;
   int flagB = 0;

   while (1) {
    char c;

    c = getopt (argc, argv, "abc:");
    if (c == -1) {
        break;
    }
    switch (c) {
    case 'a':
        flagA = 1;
         //cout<<optarg<<endl; //I tried printing the value but it only prints the second  flag value
        break;
    case 'b':
        flagB = 1;
        cout<<optarg<<endl;
        break;
    case 'c':
        cout<<optarg<<endl;
        break;
   case '?':
    default:
       cout<<"Usage: %s [-a] [-b <something>].\n", argv[0]<<endl;
    }
   if(flagA > 0){
    //do something using the values of flagA and flagC 
   }
   else if(flagB > 0){
      //do something using the values of flagB and flagC

   }
 }
 return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems with the code, but the key one is in your invocation of `getopt()`.  You have the option control string `"abc:"`, which means that neither `-a` nor `-b` takes an option.

Assuming you're using a POSIX standard version of [`getopt()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html) and not GNU [`getopt()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt_long), then when you run either:

```
./filename -a somevalue -c anothervalue
./filename -b somevalue -c anothervalue
```

the `somevalue` after the first flag means that options are finished and the remaining arguments are non-option arguments.  GNU `getopt()`, in the absence of the environment variable `POSIXLY_CORRECT`, will permute the argument list so that `-c anothervalue` is also recognized (and the arguments are permuted such that `somevalue` ends up at the end).

Your code would be better written:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600 
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int flagA = 0;
    int flagB = 0;
    int opt;
    char *c_opt = 0;

    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "abc:")) != -1)
    {
        switch (opt)
        {
        case 'a':
            flagA = 1;
            cout << "A: " << flagA << "\n";
            break;
        case 'b':
            flagB = 1;
            cout << "B: " << flagB << "\n";
            break;
        case 'c':
            c_opt = optarg;
            cout << "C: " << c_opt << "\n";
            break;
        default:
            cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " [-a] [-b] [-c <something>]\n";
            return -1;
        }
    }

    if (flagA)
    {
        // do something using the values of flagA and c_opt (if set)
    }
    else if (flagB)
    {
        // do something using the values of flagB and c_opt (if set)
    }
    else if (c_opt)
    {
        // do something using just c_opt (neither flagA nor flagB is set)
    }
    else
    {
        // do something if no options are specified (report error?)
    }

    for (int i = optind; i < argc; i++)
        cout << "File: " << i << ": " << argv[i] << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The code above (as amended) compiles cleanly with GCC 4.9.1 on Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite):

```
g++ -O3 -g -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror opt.cpp -o opt
```

The BSD-ish `getopt()` hews close to the POSIX standard, so the result I get is:

```
$ ./opt -a 5 -c something
A: 1
File: 2: 5
File: 3: -c
File: 4: something
$
```

---

[florw.wat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4246527/florw-wat) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26900980/getopt-command-line-get-values-c/26901758?noredirect=1#comment42356260_26901758):

> I want the `-a` and `-b` options to take an argument. What I am trying to do is I have two functions which take two arguments, so if `-a` is set then I would like to call function `a` else if `-b` then call function `b`. I need the two values to call the functions.

Given that clarification, the code might look like:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

static void usage(const char *arg0)
{
    cerr << "Usage: " << arg0 << " [-a filename | -b filename] -c <something>\n";
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *a_opt = 0;
    char *b_opt = 0;
    char *c_opt = 0;
    int opt;

    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "a:b:c:")) != -1)
    {
        switch (opt)
        {
        case 'a':
            a_opt = optarg;
            cout << "A: " << a_opt << "\n";
            break;
        case 'b':
            b_opt = optarg;
            cout << "B: " << b_opt << "\n";
            break;
        case 'c':
            c_opt = optarg;
            cout << "C: " << c_opt << "\n";
            break;
        default:
            cerr << "Unknown option: " << optopt << "\n";
            usage(argv[0]);
            break;
        }
    }

    if (optind != argc || c_opt == 0 || (a_opt && b_opt) || (a_opt == 0 && b_opt == 0))
        usage(argv[0]);
    else if (a_opt)
        cout << "A&C: " << a_opt << " " << c_opt << "\n";
    else
        cout << "B&C: " << b_opt << " " << c_opt << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Sample run:

```
$ ./opt -a option -c something
A: option
C: something
A&C: option something
$
```

Comment: This isn't working, when I do `./filename -a 5 -c "sometext"` I am getting `Usage: ./project [-a] [-b] [-c <something>]
`

Comment: also I am on codeblocks..Ubuntu, I am not sure how do I know which one is the standard.

Comment: (1) Ubuntu uses GNU `getopt()`.  (2) Do you want the `-a` option to take an argument or not?  If if should have one, use `a:` in the option string; otherwise, use just `a` as now.  Similarly for `-b`.  Your question isn't wholly consistent in showing what you want.

Comment: I want the -a/-b option to take an argument. I will edit my question but what I am trying to do is I have two functions which take two arguments. so if `-a` is set then I would like to call function a else if `-b` then call the other one. I need to two values to call the function.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to use `optarg` with a flag, the flag must have `:` after it in the option string.

```
        c = getopt(argc, argv, "a:b:c:");
```

Your usage output statement should not have compiled for you. Also, you are attempting to mix C style format specifiers into a C++ output stream, which is incorrect.

```
            cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " [-a] [-b <something>].\n";
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but when I run ./filename -a 5 -c "some text" it only prints 5.

Comment: correct but all I want is to have the values of the flags which isn't displaying both values. `cout<<optarg<<endl;` is all I am doing just like as I have it in the code.

Comment: You did not ask for a working program, only what you were doing wrong, which this answer demonstrates. [The fixes work for me.](http://ideone.com/l99r40)